# How to get back shortcut commands in menus in various apps

Tags: menu, shortcuts

As far as I can recall, back in the day when you opened up an app (like firefox) and clicked on a menu (like File) then to the right of each entry there would be the shortcut keyboard command. I got reminded today by a friend of mine that these commands are gone now. We are both using the latest ubuntu. I miss these commands. Does anyone know how to get them back?

Comment: I think I know what you are asking for. Some software/applications have them, and I think Firefox used to have that feature.

Comment: Personally, i think this is related to how firefox developers chose to implement menus in newer releases. Unity hardly has any control over how each program generates its menus. Potentially, there may be a firefox plugin for this

Comment: Thunderbird and Kile also do not show any shortcuts but I just noticed that Libre Office still has them. So this has nothing to do with Unity then.

Comment: I couldn't find a relevant setting in about:config either

Comment: Apparently Firefox 47 still has them but Firefox 48 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Those commands never went anywhere , just press `Alt` key when you open `firefox` , the same old menu will pop in the top.

**EDIT 1 :**

Well when I press alt I have it in my browser.
[image]

**EDIT 2 :**
Well a little misunderstanding but see here when you press the `Alt` key , you can see the some letters are underlined and thats the shortcut for that ,Such as in nautilus to make a new folder press `Alt` + `F` key. Tada.

[image]
[image]

Cheers

Comment: Pressing the Alt-key didn't change anything for me

Comment: If you are using unity then just point your cursor in the title bar it should change to that menu.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for. For an example of what OP is asking for, open a Nautilus window and click on a menu. You will see a keyboard shortcut next to each item in that menu that has such a shortcut assigned.

Comment: hmm got it, sorry for not understanding it first

Comment: @KuntalMajumder I see from your screenshot that you actually do have the keyboard shortcuts in your menu. How did you do that?

Comment: I havent done anything , I am using firefox 47.0.1 with Arch Linux.

Comment: I see, so that feature is removed in Firefox 48 then, which is what I have.

Comment: It seems to be removed in several other apps too